# Unable to read from Azure database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, connection-string

I'm trying to read/write to an Azure database but I receive the following error message when using the SqlDataReader in my code below:

```
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

I can connect to the database in SQL Server Management Studio. Any suggestions as to why this might be and how to resolve this?

My C# code:

```
        string connectionString = "Server=tcp:[xxxxx].database.windows.net,1433;Database=[xxxxx];User ID=[xxxxx]@[xxxxx];Password=[xxxxx];Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sql = "SELECT [xxxxx], [xxxxx] FROM [xxxxx]";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = Database.ExecuteReader(cmd))
                {
                    if (!reader.Read())
                    {
                        throw new Exception("[xxxxx] not found.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        name = Database.GetStringValue(reader, "[xxxxx]", "");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the IP you are connecting to the database form is white listed on your database configuration in Azure. Sounds like a [firewall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee621782.aspx) problem to me.

Comment: I've been told that my IP has been white listed and I can connect to the database in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: But is Management Studio on the same server you are running your production code from? Or are you connecting from your desktop or different development environment? If you are sure the environment is the same, then it may not be a firewall issue.

Comment: Yes, Management Studio is on the same server as my code.

Comment: Ok, after a second look I suspect this part of your connection string might be the issue: "User ID=[xxxxx]@[xxxxx]". Notice the use of an @ character which I assume Azure is interpreting as a user and a domain. I think Azure SQL server only supports SQL Authentication (no windows authentication yet). So check your credentials, make sure you are using the ones provisioned by SQL Azure.

Comment: I've managed to connect to the database by re-writing my code though I don't know why my second attempt works yet my first didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but rearranging my code to the following below resolved my issue and I could read the data that I wanted.

```
        string connectionString = "Server=tcp: [xxxxx].database.windows.net,1433;Database=[xxxxx];User ID=[xxxxx]@[xxxxx];Password=[xxxxx];Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;";

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT [xxxxx] FROM [xxxxx]", myConnection);
            reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (!(reader.Read()))
                throw new Exception("[xxxxx] not found.");
            else
                cert = reader["[xxxxx]"].ToString();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```